# How to select only top layer using Select OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I use this  part of code to make all layers selectable:

```
this.selectFeaturesClick = new Select({
  style: selectFeatureStyle,
  condition: click,
  multi: false,
  filter: (feature: FeatureLike) => {
    console.log(feature);

    return (
      !this.drawingService.editFeaturePoint &&
      feature.getGeometry().getType() !== LayerType.point
    );
  },
});
```

The issue is I got all layers selected after click. How to make only top layers selected?
This `console.log(feature);` showesme two messages by count of visible layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either specify the layer in the `layers` option

```
  layers: [topLayer],
```

or test the layer in the filter function

```
  filter: (feature, layer) => {
    return (
      !this.drawingService.editFeaturePoint &&
      feature.getGeometry().getType() !== LayerType.point &&
      layer === topLayer
    );
  },
```